# SSL certificate requirement

Tags: security, ssl

If I install Magento on a site which does not have SSL certificates
configured then will I be able to configure Magento to use an SSL
certificate at a later time without having to reinstall. Is there
any reason why I would want to avoid this path?

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you need to do to configure Magento for SSL is setting the `Secure Base URL` to use `https` instead of `http` under `System > Configuration > General - Web > Secure`.

So starting off with or without an SSL certificate doesn't really matter from a technical Magento point of view.

However, a small sidenote: I've come across a few (Dutch) Payment Service Providers that require HTTPS connections for payments. So make sure to check if this is not the case with your Payment Service Provider (PSP).

Comment: Thank you. The XAMPP BitNami Magento installation configures `http://myhost.com:80/magento/` for both the Unsecure and Secure Base URLs. I've changed the latter to `https://myhost.com:443/magento/` and selected "Use Secure URLs in Admin" which causes a redirect from http to https whenever I access the backend, which is what I wanted. Also, setting the "Use Secure URLs in Frontend", as expected, doesn't cause every frontend web page to be served via https, which makes sense, but again as expected, it causes the http to change to https when Iclick on the "Checkout" button. Thks for your post.